# Combine two lists and match values

Tags: c#

Inside the "Distributions" variable is a key called "Deadline" which contains a date.

I would like to add **"RealDeadline = i.Deadline,"**. All the other lines works fine, but I just cant find a way to add the last thing.

The match has to be made on AssignmentId which is the key for the whole combine. basically if the HandInData.Where(...) could just add the value of "Deadline" from "Distributions", that would do the trick..

```
var HandInData = db.Handins.ToList();
var Distributions = db.Distributes.ToList();

var AssignNames = HandInData.Where(a => Distributions.Any(x => x.AssignmentId == a.AssignmentId));

var StudentsHandedInDataFeed = AssignNames.Select(i => new {
    *RealDeadline = i.Deadline, (this is not working..)*
    Help = i.NeedHelp,
    Done = i.Done,
    AssName = i.Assignment.AssignmentName,
    Student = i.Student.StudentName,
    DeadlineInTimeformat = i.Assignment.AssignmentDeadline,
    HandedInInTimeformat = i.HandedInDate,
    Deadline = i.Assignment.AssignmentDeadline.ToString(),
    HandedIn = i.HandedInDate.ToString()
});


public class Handin {
    public int HandinId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int AssignmentId { get; set; }

    public bool? Done { get; set; }
    public bool? NeedHelp { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? HandedInDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The value is not there, there is no error. If i access the "i" variable the key "deadline" is not there. As i said in my question. Idk how to many it more clear.

Comment: "deadline", or "realdeadline"?

Comment: RealDeadline is a key that i can make up. I can choose any ex. bananas. Deadline is the value that i cant access. As i said in my question.

Comment: Oh, `i.Deadline`! Well, clearly there is no such property on whatever class `Handins` is

Comment: Or it could possibly be non-public

Comment: Deadline is in Distributions

Comment: As I'm reading your code, `i` is a single instance of `Handins`. Could you add the source for `Handins` to your question.

Comment: Blorgbeard looks to have the answer. Alternatively consider whether you wanted Distribute as a virtual property (and DistributeId) on Handins if this is Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the two lists. You can do it with LINQ syntax like this:

```
var StudentsHandedInDatFeed = 
    from h in HandInData
    join d in Distributions on h.AssignmentId equals d.AssignmentId
    select new {
        RealDeadline = d.Deadline,
        Help = h.NeedHelp,
        // etc
    };
```

The join will only include values from `HandInData` where there is a matching value in `Distributions`, so this takes care of your `Where(a => Distributions.Any(...` code as well.

Comment: Omg, that is it. I totally could not have figured that one out my self. Its almost 01:00 am.. ive been at it for more than 3 hours now.. Thanks man.